# Arduino LCD Display burger glitch a the end

Tags: arduino, lcd

I'm actually trying to display some text on a classic 16x2 LCD display.
Here's my code :

```
LiquidCrystal lcd(10, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3);

void setup(){
   lcd.begin(16, 2);
   WriteToLcd(true, "hello world.");
}

void WriteToLcd(bool clear, String msg) {
 if (clear) {
   lcd.clear();
 }
 lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
 lcd.println(msg);
 SerialUSB.println(msg);
}
```

The problem is I've go this result on the screen :
[image]

How can I remove these two burger a the end ?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem come from.
I just need to replace `lcd.println(msg);` by `lcd.print(msg);`